# Python Dataframe (How can I get the same output from the first code)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tweepy

While using the below code, I don't get the dataframed output

```
print("What you wanna search \n 1. User timeline \n 2. Hashtag/Keyword search \n Enter either 1 or 2")
choice = input()

numtweet = 100

if choice == '1' :
  print("Enter Twitter Handle you want to search for")
  words = input()
  print("Enter Date since The Tweets are required in yyyy-mm--dd")
  date_since = input()
  scrapeuser(words, date_since, numtweet)
  print('Scraping has completed!')

elif choice == '2':
  print("Enter Twitter HashTag to search for")
  words = input()
  print("Enter Date since The Tweets are required in yyyy-mm--dd")
  date_since = input()
  scrape(words, date_since, numtweet)

print("Do you wanna see the data scraped? [y/n]")
decision = input()

if (decision == 'Y') or (decision == 'y') :
  # print(pd.read_csv("scraped_tweets.csv"))
  if choice == '1' :
    df_scraped = pd.read_csv("scraped_tweets_user.csv")
    df_scraped
  elif choice == '2' :
    df_scraped = pd.read_csv("scraped_tweets.csv")
    df_scraped
```

and the output was [image]
I didn't any output after calling `df_scraped`

While I get the output as I want while I run this code separately as

```
df_scraped = pd.read_csv("scraped_tweets_user.csv")
df_scraped
```

the output was [image]

How can I get the same output from the first code

Comment: do you need `print(df_scraped)`  instead `df_scraped` ?

Comment: while doing that I get a different output